# JQuery : select element inside hidden column of datatables

Tags: jquery, hidden

I have code like this :

```
<table class="table" id="items">
  <thead>
    <tr>            
      <th>Acc Name</th>
      <th class="hjob">Job</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>                
      <td><input class="acname"></td>
      <td><input class="job"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On dataTables definition, column header with class "hjob" is hidden using :

```
$('#items').DataTable({ 
  columnDefs: [ { visible: false, targets: 'hjob' } ]
});
```

Then, I want to select all element (including the hidden one) inside tr tag

```
$('tbody').find('tr:first').find('input').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

But, I got only the "accname" (can't get "job") class. Is it possible for selecting element/cell inside hidden column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using [tag:datatables] then you have to use the datatables API and not jquery to get data from the data

Answer (score 0):

Is your table wrapped in `table` elements? Adding them makes it work as you describe – the classes for both inputs are outputted:

```js
$('tbody').find('tr:first').find('input').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.hjob, .job {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>          
      <th>Acc Name</th>
      <th class="hjob">Job</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>              
      <td><input class="acname"></td>
      <td><input class="job"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this code just hide the title of column, not column as a whole including the contents like we hide a spreadsheet column.

Comment: Ok, the code was edited, but no, this is just hide content of column not column it self, the table column still in there and occupying space of screen. I use dataTables and just edit my question to be more clear. Thanks.